# What happens when ==, CompareTo(), and Equals() do not agree?

Tags: c#, linq, operator-overloading, icomparable, iequatable

I have a program I wrote some years back to find "good" binary operators for bytes; byte `A` is left multiplied by byte `B` to yield byte `C`. The operator is defined as 256x256 byte matrix. `A` stripped down version of the class implementation is below.

`Equals()` is true IFF all 65536 bytes in the array are the same.

`CompareTo()` compares the Linearity of the operator into a continuum of more linear (bad for cryto) to less linear (good for crypto).

So it is possible for two instances, `A` and `B`, that both of the following are true:

```
A.Equals(B) = false
(A.ComparesTo(B) == 0) = true
```

My question is less: Is this a good idea? I know the answer is No, but given the large computational cost of measuring linearity and the narrow nature of my problem this design works.  Also code similar to:

```
if (localMinimumOperator < globalMinimumOperator)
{
  localMinimumOperator = globalMinimumOperator;
}
```

is easier for me to read.

My question is: What are the consequences of this divergence among: ==, `CompareTo()== 0`, and `Equals()`? or alternately:
Is there list of which LINQ extensions methods describing which extension use which interface (`IEquatable` or `IComparable`)?

Something more concise than this MSDN article on [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

For example:

```
IEnumerable<BinaryOperation> distinct = orgList.Distinct();
```

calls `Equals(BinaryOperator)` as per: [`Enumerable.Distinct<TSource>` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  as does `Contains()`. I understand that `Sort()` and `OrderBy()` use calls to `CompareTo()`.

But what about `FindFirst()` and `BinarySearch()`?

My example class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace Jww05
{
  public class BinaryOperation : IEquatable<BinaryOperation>, IComparable<BinaryOperation>
  {
    #region ClassMembers

    public List<List<byte>> TruthTable
    {
      get
      {
        // I don't like giving out the underlying list if I help it
        var retVal = new List<List<byte>>(OperatorDefintion);
        return retVal;
      }
    }

    // private data store for TruthTable
    private List<List<byte>> OperatorDefintion { get; set; }

    public BinaryOperation()
    {
      // initial state is the Identity operator
      OperatorDefintion = new List<List<byte>>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
      {
        var curRow = new List<byte>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
        {
          curRow.Add((byte)(i + j));
        }
        OperatorDefintion.Add(curRow);
      }
    }

    private long MeasureOperatorLinearity()
    {
      var diagonalOffsets = new byte[] { 255, 0, 1 };

      /*
       * Code that measures linearity in the original code used the Fast Walsh Hadamard Transform.
       * That should go here, but it is removed because the FWHT is clutter for the purposes of this question.
       *
       * Since I needed a stub for this, I decided to exacerbate the differnece
       * between CompareTo() == 0 and Equals()
       * by returning an arbitrary int in lieu of the long CPU intensive Fast Walsh Hadamard Transform.
       *
       * If the matrices are identical on an element-by-element basis, then the Faux Linearity will be the the same.
       * If the faux linearity (sum of terms on the main diagonal and corners) are the same, the underlying matrices could be different on an element-by-element basis.
       */
      long fauxLinearityMeasure = 0;
      for (var currRow = 0; currRow < OperatorDefintion.Count(); ++currRow)
      {
        fauxLinearityMeasure *= 5;
        fauxLinearityMeasure = diagonalOffsets.Select(diagonalOffset => (byte)(currRow + diagonalOffset))
                                              .Aggregate(fauxLinearityMeasure, (current, offestedIndex) => current + (OperatorDefintion[offestedIndex][currRow]));
      }

      return (int)fauxLinearityMeasure;
    }

    #endregion ClassMembers

    #region ComparisonOperations

    public int CompareTo(BinaryOperation other)
    {
      long otherLinearity = other.MeasureOperatorLinearity();
      long thisLinearity = MeasureOperatorLinearity();
      long linearityDiff = thisLinearity - otherLinearity;

      // case the differnece of the linarity measures into {-1, 0, 1}
      return (0 < linearityDiff) ? 1
           : (0 > linearityDiff) ? -1
           : 0;
    }

    public static bool operator >(BinaryOperation lhs, BinaryOperation rhs)
    {
      if (ReferenceEquals(null, lhs) ||
          ReferenceEquals(null, rhs))
      {
        return false;
      }
      return (0 < lhs.CompareTo(rhs));
    }

    public static bool operator <(BinaryOperation lhs, BinaryOperation rhs)
    {
      if (ReferenceEquals(null, lhs) ||
          ReferenceEquals(null, rhs))
      {
        return false;
      }
      return (0 > lhs.CompareTo(rhs));
    }

    public static bool operator <=(BinaryOperation lhs, BinaryOperation rhs)
    {
      if (ReferenceEquals(null, lhs) ||
          ReferenceEquals(null, rhs))
      {
        return false;
      }

      // equals is cheap
      if (lhs.Equals(rhs))
      {
        return true;
      }

      return (0 > lhs.CompareTo(rhs));
    }

    public static bool operator >=(BinaryOperation lhs, BinaryOperation rhs)
    {
      if (ReferenceEquals(null, lhs) ||
          ReferenceEquals(null, rhs))
      {
        return false;
      }

      // equals is cheap
      if (lhs.Equals(rhs))
      {
        return true;
      }

      return (0 < lhs.CompareTo(rhs));
    }

    #endregion ComparisonOperations

    #region EqualityOperators

    public bool Equals(BinaryOperation other)
    {
      if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
      {
        return false;
      }

      var otherTruthTable = other.TruthTable;
      var thisTruthTable = TruthTable;
      var isEquals = true;
      for (int currRow = 0; currRow < thisTruthTable.Count(); ++currRow)
      {
        isEquals = isEquals && thisTruthTable[currRow].SequenceEqual(otherTruthTable[currRow]);
      }

      return isEquals;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
      return Equals(obj as BinaryOperation);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
      return OperatorDefintion.SelectMany(currRow => currRow)
                              .Aggregate(1, (current, currByte) => current * 5 + currByte);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(BinaryOperation lhs, BinaryOperation rhs)
    {
      if (ReferenceEquals(null, lhs) ||
          ReferenceEquals(null, rhs))
      {
        return false;
      }

      return (0 == lhs.CompareTo(rhs));
    }

    public static bool operator !=(BinaryOperation lhs, BinaryOperation rhs)
    {
      if (ReferenceEquals(null, lhs) ||
          ReferenceEquals(null, rhs))
      {
        return false;
      }

      return (0 != lhs.CompareTo(rhs));
    }

    #endregion EqualityOperators
  }
}
```

Comment: `==` is static, and LINQ uses generics. That doesn't mix. At best it could constrain the type to be a reference type, then `==` will mean reference-equality. In fact this is a common complaint about generics.

Comment: For those interested, I was measuring linearity (affine distance actually) in order to search for an operator resistant to [Linear Cryptanalysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_cryptanalysis)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are the consequences of this divergence among: ==, CompareTo()== 0, and Equals()?

Someone looking at your code in the future will truly hate you.

> or alternately: Is there list of which linq extensions methods describing which extension use which interface (IEquitable or IComparable)?

I think that you've found most of it by yourself. A good rule of thumb is that usually there is nothing surprising in what interface is used by which LINQ function (no surprises is one of features of good design - unlike yours). For example: it's quite obvious that to sort elements it is necessary to know in which particular order should elements go, equality/inequality alone are not sufficient for this. `BinarySearch` also needs to know "which way to go" during search - if element is larger than current it re-curses into upper part of sorted array, if smaller it goes into lower. Again: obviously it needs `IComparable`. For `Distinct` `Equals` and `GetHashCode` suffice - sorting is not needed to determine a set of unique elements. And so on.

Comment: Someone looking at your code in the future will truly hate you.

Comment: I think this is the best answer.  *Don't Do This!* But, if you are so foolish as to ignore this advice, then you are on your own and you have to examine the particulars of each and every operation you use that that may be confused by having a surprising divergence between IEquatable and IComprarable.

Comment: It is better for the methods of comparison to yield different results when appropriate, than to coerce their meanings so they match.  If objects X and Y include no feature that would allow them to be ranked, then `X.CompareTo(Y)` must yield zero.  If the objects are clearly unequal, however, then `X.Equals(Y)` should return false.  Classes for which people might want to test reference equality should avoid adding an override of `==`, since doing so will make use of the `==` operator more awkward.